# ignore the /virtual subfolder/ that didn't exist in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I have a multi-language website and I want to display the current language in the URI which is something like this:

URI:

```
www.domain.com/en/
www.domain.com/en/folder1/
www.domain.com/de/
www.domain.com/de/folder2/
```

DIRECTORY:

```
public_html/
public_html/folder1/
public_html/
public_html/folder2/
```

Then the en or de will be saved in a cookie to process the language code.
Is it possible to do these? Even without the actual folder of the en or de?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the URI to remove the language and use the `CO` flag to set a cookie. So something like this (in the htaccess file in your document root):

```
RewriteEngine On
# first check the the folder/file actually exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]{2}/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
# rewrite and set cookie:
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2 [L,CO=lang:$1:domain.com]
```

This will set a cookie named **lang** with the value equal to the 2 letter prefix in the original URI and with the domain as **domain.com**.

Comment: The code is working. Thank you!

How about if I enter a url something like this:
www.domain.com/folder1/file.php

can I insert the en/ between the domain name and the folder1?
Like this:
www.domain.com/en/folder1/file.php

Is it possible in .htaccess?
I can work it out in php language, but I also want to test if it will work in htaccess, and what is the best choice between the two.